# Can't deploy Nuxt 3 app either to GitHub Pages or Netlify

Tags: deployment, nuxt.js, github-pages, netlify, nuxt3

So I coded a simple landing page app to learn Nuxt 3 and I've been trying to deploy it to either GitHub Pages or Netlify without success.
It's a very simple app, basically three different pages, very few components, and one single layout.
At the moment, I've redone the whole app following the Nuxt docs very closely and get the following error when I `npm run generate`:

```
Unexpected identifier
  at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:119:18)  
  at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:468:14)  
  at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:68:21)
```

I'm using Nuxt 3.7.3, Node 18.18.0 and Tailwind 3.3.3.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Nuxt3, note that Netlify has [built-in support](https://docs.netlify.com/integrations/frameworks/nuxt/#automatic-framework-detection) for Nuxt3 deployment, and 'generate' command is unsupported.

Comment: Ok, but simply pointing to the right repo and asking Netlify to deploy doesn’t work. In the end I tried Vercel and it worked right away on first try. I simply asked it to deploy and it went without any hassle. I was expecting Netlify (or GitHub pages, for that matter) to do the same, but it seems I’m missing something.

Comment: @FredBarros It's because Nuxt3 uses Nitro, and Nitro will automatically recognize the running environment and use [the correct provider](https://nitro.unjs.io/deploy/providers/netlify).

Comment: I [tried `generate` on Netlify](https://app.netlify.com/sites/fanbook-bot-tools/deploys/64ec47ad8c8014657d2c04d8) 1 month ago and failed, then I found `build` is OK